# unable to open X server

Tags: terminal, xvfb

I am trying to generate a screenshot of a firefox window in my terminal, but I  keep getting an error:

```
root@host [~]# DISPLAY=:1 firefox http://www.cnn.com & sleep 5 && DISPLAY=:1 import -window root -crop 1264x948+0+25 -quality 90 /usr/local/apache/htdocs/screenshot1.jpg && pkill firefox
[1] 30200
import: unable to open X server `:1' @ import.c/ImportImageCommand/364.
```

Why is this happening? How can I fix it?

Comment: Can you confirm that Firefox displays on `:1`?

Comment: How do i check that?

Comment: If you have any other running Firefox (on your main X display, probably), check that they aren't displaying `www.cnn.com`. If they aren't, and Firefox doesn't produce any error message, chances are good that it is indeed displaying on `:1`. If you are running `Xvfb` as your tags suggest, use its `-fbdir` option and look at the screen with `xwud </fbdir-directory/Xvfb_screen0` (and you can even take screenshots with `convert /fbdir-directory/Xvfb_screen0 -crop … screenshot1.png`).

Comment: Do you have a display `:1`? Telling ff to display on a new display won't work if it's not there.

Comment: Well i am using DISPLAY=:1 firefox http://www.cnn.com & sleep 5 && DISPLAY=:1 import -window root -crop 1264x948+0+25 -quality 90 /usr/local/apache/htdocs/screenshot1.jpg && pkill firefox

Comment: What do you recommend i use for the code then?

Comment: @mystycs `ps aux| grep X` - paste the output.

Answer (score 1):

There are two possibilities:

1. You are not running an xserver on :1. This is probable because most people only run one xserver and by default it is on :0. This can be overcome by starting a xserver on :1. It is not too difficult to run a second xserver on another virtual console. Other popular choices are Xvnc and xvfb which do not depend on hardware.
2. You are running a xserver on :1 but you do not have permission to use it. Read man xauth.